# How to install iWork '09 onto an external volume?

Tags: macos, mac, installation, iwork

I want to install iWork '09 onto an external volume but the installer doesn't allow that. Most Mac applications don't really care where you install them, but some from Apple, like iWork, is especially nitpicky. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed it on Root already and tried dragging the applications to the other volume?

Comment: +1 You're right that would work. However, the startup drive of this particular Mac is full to the brim but it has a 1 TB drive attached to it. I was wondering if there's a way to directly install it there.

Comment: But doesn't the installer have a "Select volume" pane where you can choose the other disk? I installed iWork recently, but I took the defaults and don't remember specifics. Do you have other apps you could move over first to make room?